# Verificar URL vinda de document.referrer

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte situação.

1. Quando o usuário acessa o site: www.site.com.br eu verifico se existe o parâmetro sc=2 no fim da URL, se existir ele consegue acessar o site, se não existir ele é redirecionado para www.site.com.br/sistema/401
2. Nessa página www.site.com.br/sistema/401 eu salvo a página de onde o usuário veio:

   var ref = document.referrer
3. Nessa mesma página eu tenho um formulário que o usuário insere seu e-mail para fazer "login". Após inserir o e-mail ele é redirecionado para a página que ele estava antes através do código abaixo e insiro o parâmetro sc=2 no fim da url:

   window.location.href = ref + (/\?.{1,}=/.test(ref) ? '&' : '?') + 'sc=2';
4. Porém imagine que o usuário acesse direto a página: www.site.com.br/sistema/401 ou seja, essa será a página que ficará salva no document.referrer aí quando a pessoa fizer login ela será redirecionada para essa mesma página e o usuário ficará em loop infinito tentando fazer login.

Como eu faria para verificar se o document.referrer for igual a uma pagina específica ele ficasse com outra URL? EX:

```
var ref = document.referrer;
if (ref == 'https://www.site.com.br/Sistema/401'){ ref = 'https://www.site.com.br'; }
window.location.href = ref + (/\?.{1,}=/.test(ref) ? '&' : '?') + 'sc=2';
```

Tentei fazer da forma acima, mas não funcionou onde eu errei?
No caso quando o usuário entrar em:

> https://www.site.com.br/Sistema/401

ele deveria ser direcionado para:

> https://www.site.com.br

Porém não é isso que acontece, ele continua sendo redirecionado para https://www.site.com.br/Sistema/401

Comment: O que não funcionou? Me parece não haver problema nesse código se o objetivo era apenas alterar o valor da variável `ref`.

Comment: Editei a pergunta @Sam, até foi você mesmo quem me ajudou em outra questão sobre esse document.referrer

Comment: Já tentou entrar na URL `https://www.site.com.br` direto no navegador pra ver se volta pro `https://www.site.com.br/Sistema/401`? Pelo que pude perceber deveria fazer o redirecionamento para `https://www.site.com.br`, exceto que algo no servidor esteja fazendo voltar pra URL do `ref` ou no index da segunda URL esteja redirecionando de volta.

Comment: Se eu entrar no https://www.site.com.br aí ele direciona para a página 401 que é onde a pessoa insere o e-mail, aí depois ele redireciona novamente para a pagina https://www.site.com.br sem problemas.

Comment: O que eu precisava é q se a primeira passe fosse https://www.site.com.br/Sistema/401 ele direcionasse para https://www.site.com.br pq senão o usuario fica em loop infinito colocando o email dele

Comment: Vc tem que armazenar alguma coisa (talvez uma session) pra saber quando não redirecionar pra a página 401.

Comment: @Sam vou editar a pergunta, acho que não está ficando claro como é o funcionamento.

Comment: Blz, dei uma lida rápida na edição e vou ler novamente para tentar entender melhor, mas já adiantando, quando o usuário acessa a página direto, o referrer fica vazio, ao contrário do que vc diz aqui: "_Porém imagine que o usuário acesse direto a página: www.site.com.br/sistema/401 ou seja, essa será a página que ficará salva no document.referrer_"

Comment: Então talvez funcione se eu colocar: if (!ref){ ref = 'https://www.site.com.br/'; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bastou colocar:

```
 if (!ref){ ref = 'site.com.br'; }
```

Que funcionou

Answer (score 1):

var x = document.referrer;

```js
var rfr = document.referrer;
//mostrando o link em um alerta
alert(rfr);
//mostrando o alerta no html de uma div
$('#ssss').html("O link visitado anteriormente foi : "+ rfr);
if (rfr=="Site acessado"){
window.location.href = "Site para carregar";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ssss"></div>
```